# How to initialize a discriminated union from another discriminated union in F#?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

With the following F# definitions, how can the Model be initialized?

```
open System
open System.Windows

type ContactDetail = { Id: Guid; Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Internet      = { Id: Guid; Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type PhoneNumber   = { Id: Guid; Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }
type Address       = { Id: Guid; Name: string; Content: string; Text: string }

    module Testing =    
        type Details =
            | ContactDetail of ContactDetail
            | Internet      of Internet 
            | PhoneNumber   of PhoneNumber
            | Address       of Address
            
            
        let contactDetail  : ContactDetail = {Id=Guid.NewGuid(); Name="Contact Detail"; Content="Content for Contact Detail"; Text="here is the contact detail text" }    
        let internet       : Internet = {Id=Guid.NewGuid(); Name="Internet";       Content="Content for Internet";       Text="here is the internet text" }
        let phoneNumber    : PhoneNumber =  {Id=Guid.NewGuid();Name="Phone Number";   Content="Content for phone number";   Text="here is the phone number text" }
        let address        : Address = {Id=Guid.NewGuid(); Name="Address";        Content="Content for Address";        Text="here is the Address text" }
       
        let details   = [ContactDetail contactDetail
                         Internet      internet
                         PhoneNumber   phoneNumber
                         Address       address
                         ]

        type DetailsWithId = DetailsWithId of Details * Guid

        type Model = {
          ClickCount: int
          Message: string
          Details: DetailsWithId list
        }
```

More specifically, I need Details of the Model to be a list (or seq). Is type DetailsWithId already a list because of type Details?

TIA

Comment: DetailsWithId is a pair of Details and Guid. Your Details in the Model is a list of pairs. In what format do you want the end result to be? Perhaps try to specify the type of a function that takes an instance of Model and yields the things you want. Then it would be possible to provide a solution. It will involve an application of a `map` function most likely.

Comment: The simplest instance of Model with at least one instance of Details would be `{ ClickCount = 0; Message = ""; Details = [(contactDetail,Guid.NewGuid())] }`. It seems to me that the name of the type `Details` is not the best possible, because an instance always captures just one detail. Perhaps a better structure would make Details a record and just use options in those details which can be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comment, a value of your `Details` type represents just a single detail - one of the several possible details listed. A value of type `Details list` is a list of details (which can possibly be empty, or it can include multiple instances of the same detail type).

If this is not what you need, then it'd be good to find a model that better captures the structure of your domain.

If this is what you want, then I would still change two things about your data types:

- First, I'd rethink how you're storing IDs. In your model, you have `Id` field in the individual records, but then, again, in the `DetailsWithId` type. I suppose the question is how to automatically copy the ID from the record to the ID in the `DetailsWithId` type. There is no easy way to do this, but it's better to design your types so that you do not need to do this.
- Second, your four record types i.e. `ContactDetail`, `Internet`, etc. are all the same. Wouldn't it be easier to use just one type?

I think working with your data would be a lot easier (unless there is something about your domain that you did not document in the question), if you used a type definition like this:

```
type DetailKind =
    | ContactDetail 
    | Internet
    | PhoneNumber
    | Address

type Detail =
  { Id: Guid
    Name: string
    Content: string
    Text: string 
    Kind: DetailKind }

type Details = Detail list
```

Comment: The reason ContactDetail, Internet, etc...are the same (at the moment) is to allow easy wpf windows. Down the line, these will begin to differ with the addition of other fields. Thanks.